# Unable to pass data on row click

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

What am i doing wrong int the below code. I am not getting any error also I am not getting the results. 
  1.  The alerts are appearing.
  2.  I tried harding the ceid value   still that value si not getting passed to function inside the EVerifyModuleI9Service.
  eg : I hard coded EVerifyModuleI9Service.getEmployeeInformation(53) but always 0 is being sent to the function.

Note : LoadViewSelected is to load a view it takes the url of the view and the js file as parameters.

HTML (ListEverify.cshtml):

```
<div ng-app="EVerifyModule">
  <div class="row" ng-controller="EVerifyController as ECtrl">
    <table class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover table-condensed">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th ng-click="sortdata('name')"> Employee Name
            <span class="glyphicon sort-icon"></span>
          </th>
          <th ng-click="sortdata('dateHire')">
            Hire Date
            <span class="glyphicon sort-icon"></span>
          </th>
          <th ng-click="sortdata('phoneNumber')">
            Phone Number
            <span class="glyphicon sort-icon"></span>
          </th>
          <th>
            E-Verify
            <span class="glyphicon sort-icon"></span>
          </th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="emp in Employees" ng-click="storeIds(emp)">
          <td>{{emp.name}}</td>
          <td>{{emp.dateHire | date:'MM-dd-yyyy'}}</td>
          <td>{{emp.phoneNumber}}</td>
          <td><a class="btn-sm btn-primary pull-right" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="LoadViewSelected('/EVerify/EVerify/EVerifySubmit', 'EVerifyModule');">E-Verify</a></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

EVerifyModel.js

```
var EVerifyModule = angular.module('EVerifyModule', ['angularFileUpload', 'ui.bootstrap', 'angularUtils.directives.dirPagination']);
EVerifyModule.factory('EVerifyModuleService', ['$http', '$window', function($http, $window) {
  return {
    GetEmployeeList: function(companyId) {
      return $http({
        url: '/api/EVerify/GetEmployeeList',
        method: 'POST',
        data: companyId
      });
    }
  };
}]);

EVerifyModule.factory('EVerifyModuleI9Service', ['$http', function($http) {

  return {
    getEmployeeInformation: function(id) {
      return $http({
        url: '/api/EVerify/GetEmployeeInfo',
        method: 'GET',
        params: {
          Id: id
        }
        // data: id
      });
    }
  };

}]);

EVerifyModule.service('DataToPersistService', function(param) {
  ceId = param;
});

EVerifyModule.controller('EVerifyController', ['$scope', '$http', '$compile', 'EVerifyModuleService', '$timeout', function($scope, $http, $compile, EVerifyModuleService, $timeout) {
  $scope.storeIds = function(emp) {
    alert(emp.id);
    alert(emp.name);
    DataToPersistService.function(emp.id);
  }

  EVerifyModuleService.GetEmployeeList(61).then(function(response) {
    $scope.Employees = response.data.Employees;
  });
}]);

EVerifyModule.controller('EVerifyI9Controller', ['$scope', '$http', '$compile', 'EVerifyModuleI9Service', function($scope, $http, $compile, EVerifyModuleI9Service) {
  EVerifyModuleI9Service.getEmployeeInformation(ceId).then(function(response) {
    if (response != null) {

      $scope.employeeInfo = response.data.EmployeeInfo;
    }
  });
}]);
```

Comment: Can you clarify? Are you saying that EVerifyModuleI9Service.getEmployeeInformation(53) and getEmployeeInformation(id) is receiving an id of 0?

Comment: getEmployeeInformation is a function under EVerifyModuleI9Service.  When I try to call getEmployeeInformation either hardcoding or passing ceid it is receiving an id of 0. like EVerifyModuleI9Service.getEmployeeInformation(53)  the value 53 is not getting passed. instead it is receiving an id of 0.

Answer (score 0):

```
<a class="btn-sm btn-primary pull-right" href="javascript:void(0)"  onclick="LoadViewSelected('/EVerify/EVerify/EVerifySubmit', 'EVerifyModule');">E-Verify</a>
```

Replace anchor tag with button for simplicity and then replace onclick with ng-click event and make sure that u got LoadViewSelected function attached to ur $scope.